# Token with KeyId in payload -> IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid

Tags: .net, jwt, token

I use jwks url to retreive the public key of the token.
My token has the "kid" parameter in the payload instead of the head of the token.

When I try to validate the token, I always receive this error : "IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid"

I tryed to seek by myself the correct public key (based on kid value) and set to TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey without success. I always have the same error.

I also try to set all keys to IssuerSigningKeys property, and set TryAllIssuerSigningKeys = true without success.

Based on JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs code, I try to verify the token by my own, witout success.  signatureProvider.Verify(encodedBytes, signatureBytes) call raises this error: "IDX10686: Unable to Verify, Internal VerifyFunction is not available" (see code below).

If anyone has already validatng a token with a KeyId in the payload instaed of the head, it will be appreciate if you can share you experience with me.

The jwks url retrns this kind of content:

```
{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","alg":"RS256","use":"sig","kid":"x","x5c":["xxxxxxxxx"]},
{"kty":"RSA","alg":"RS256","use":"sig","kid":"y","x5c":["yyyyyyyy"]}]}
```

Thanks.

Kind Regard.

```
private SecurityToken SignatureValidator(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
{
    var jwtToken = TokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jwtToken.RawSignature))
    {
        throw new Exception("no signature");
    }

    var keyId = jwtToken.Claims.First(p => p.Type.Equals("kid")).Value;
    RenewIssuerSigningKeysIfNeeded(keyId);//initialise _jwks
    if (_jwks == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("no public signatures");
    }

    var key = _jwks.Keys.First(p => p.KeyId == keyId);

    byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtToken.RawHeader + "." + jwtToken.RawPayload);
    byte[] signatureBytes = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(jwtToken.RawSignature);
    var cryptoProviderFactory = key.CryptoProviderFactory;
    var signatureProvider = cryptoProviderFactory.CreateForVerifying(key, jwtToken.Header.Alg);
    try
    {
        if (signatureProvider.Verify(encodedBytes, signatureBytes)) // exception:IDX10686
        {
            jwtToken.SigningKey = key;
            return jwtToken;
        }

        throw new Exception("Signature is not valid");
    }
    finally
    {
        cryptoProviderFactory.ReleaseSignatureProvider(signatureProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably done with this already, but anyways; I encountered the IDX10686 error code myself yesterday which was thrown because JsonWebKeyConverter.TryConvertToSecurityKey failed to map the Jwk to a SecurityKey. In my case, another exception was swallowed inside that function, thrown because the curve of my EC key was not recognized.